# How consume multiple endpoints at same time using Kotlin Coroutine in a BackEnd Controller

Tags: java, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

Context: I found few tutorials explaining how consume mutilple endpoints from Kotlin at same time but they are based on Android and in my case it is a backend application. I have some experience using CompleteableFuture but I assume I should use Coroutine since it is a Kotlin and there is no Spring dependency.

Following some suggestions, I reached

```
@Singleton
class PersonEndpoint()
    {

    @Inject
    lateinit var employeClient: EmployeClient

    override suspend fun getPersonDetails(request: PersonRequest): PersonResponse {
        var combinedResult: String

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val resultA: String
            val resultB: String

            val employeesA = async{ employeClient.getEmployeesA()}

            val employeesB = async{ employeClient.getEmployeesB()}

            try{

                combinedResult = employeesA.await() + employeesB.await()

                print(combinedResult)

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }

        // ISSUE 1
        if I try add return over here it is not allowed. 
        I understand it is working how it is designed to work: GlobalScope is running in different thread

        }
        
    // ISSUE 2
    if I try return combinedResult over here combinedResult isn't initialized.
    I understand it is working how it is designed to work: GlobalScope is running in different thread and I can
    debug and see that return over here executes earlier than employeesA.await = employeesB.await

}
```

So, how can I execute combinedResult = employeesA.await() + employeesB.await() before returning to the client?

*** Edited after Denis/ answer

```
@Singleton
class CustomerEndpoint(){

    fun serve(): Collection<Int> {
        return runBlocking {
            async {
                getItemDouble(1)
            }
            async {
                getItemTriple(1)
            }
        }.map { it.await() }
    }

suspend fun getItemDouble(i: Int): Int {
    delay(1000)
    return i * 2
}

suspend fun getItemTriple(i: Int): Int {
    delay(1000)
    return i * 3
}

override suspend fun getPersonDetails(request: PersonRequest): PersonResponse {

    val result = serve()
    println("Got result $result")
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun main() {
    val durationMs = measureTimeMillis {
        val result = serve()
        println("Got result $result")
    }
    println("The processing is done in $durationMs ms")
}

fun serve(): Collection<Int> {
    return runBlocking {
        (1..2).map {
            async {
                getItem(it)
            }
        }.map { it.await() }
    }
}

suspend fun getItem(i: Int): Int {
    delay(1000) // Emulate item retrieval work
    return i * 2
}
```

Note that here we have two nested calls - `getItem(1)` and `getItem(2)`. We can see that they are executed in parallel as overall running time is ~1 second.

---

Edited in August 05th 2021

```
private suspend fun myMethod(): List<Any> {
    return runBlocking {
        listOf(
            async { method1() },
            async { method2() }
        ).map { it.await() }
    }
}
```

method1 and method2 are methods calling different endpoints.

Comment: Denis, thanks. How would you do if had to call different methods in parallel? I edited my question above in order to exemplify my issue.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your question? My example illustrates that sub-tasks `getItem(1)` and `getItem(2)` are running in parallel already

Comment: Sorry. Let's say you want call two different methods, one named getItemA and other call getItemB. How would you reach that? In you example you call in parallel same method. Let's say you want call in parallel two different methods like I demonstrated in my edited question with getItemDouble and getItemTripple.

Comment: In you answer you have a forEach (1..2 in Kotlin). Just remove such forEach and try call any two different methods.

Comment: It doesn't change anything - we still have two calls running in parallel. You can run this code and ensure that it's still executed in ~1 second - https://gist.github.com/denis-zhdanov/faf19c16ba295247d72e5993d6d1ac00

Comment: Denis, thanks. You answer completely my question and I had pick your answer up. In my real use case, each method will be a call to a rest endpoint. If you don't mind an extra comment, how would you deal with exception treatment using runBlocking? Would you envolve it in an try/catch? Any clue to couple with exception treatment when using runBlocking?

Comment: Welcome, Jim! A cool thing about coroutines is that they provide so-called structured concurrency, i.e. if one coroutine fails, the current coroutine context fails as well (all sibling coroutines are canceled). As coroutine contexts are hierarchical (e.g. here we create one root context in `runBlocking()` and every `async()` created a sub-context), the overall execution ends. Exception handling is done via try/catch as usual. You might want to, say, consider one sub-step (possible with sub-sub-steps) as optional, add an additional try/catch there and don't stop on exception

Comment: Just in case, a link about structured concurrency - https://elizarov.medium.com/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952

Comment: One more note, as you say that coroutines will be calling different endpoints, that is I/O, that's why it's better to use [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html). Please feel free to check corresponding [documentation chapter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads)

Comment: I tried followed your example. Reccently a deployed it to our DEV environment and figured out it hasnot been called in parallel when I checked Jaeger (our tracebility tool). Dou you see any issue on the code above? (I will edit my question adding how I implemented it)